# No error messages with Fluent Validation in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack, fluentvalidation

I am just starting to familiarise myself with ServiceStack and have come upon FluentValidation. I have followed the introductions and created a small Hello App.

My problem is that when I try to validate the request DTO **no error messages** are returned to describe how it failed validation, only a blank Json object `{}`.

Myself, I think the validation is autowired to the DTO so there should be no need for me to write any extra code.

The answer is probably blatant but I cannot see it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My code is below:

```
namespace SampleHello2
{
    [Route("/hello")]
    [Route("/hello/{Name}")]
    public class Hello
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class HelloResponse
    {
        public string Result { get; set; }
    }


    public class HelloService : Service
    {
        public object Any(Hello request)
        {
            return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, " + request.Name };
        }
    }

    public class HelloValidator : AbstractValidator<Hello>
    {
        public HelloValidator()
        {
            //Validation rules for all requests
            RuleFor(r => r.Name).NotNull().NotEmpty().Equal("Ian").WithErrorCode("ShouldNotBeEmpty");
            RuleFor(r => r.Name.Length).GreaterThan(2);
        }
    }

    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public class HelloAppHost : AppHostBase
        {
            //Tell Service Stack the name of your application and where to find your web services
            public HelloAppHost() : base("Hello Web Services", typeof(HelloService).Assembly) { }

            public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
            {
                //Enable the validation feature
                Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
                container.RegisterValidators(typeof(HelloValidator).Assembly);
                //register any dependencies your services use, e.g:
                //  container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
            }
        }

        //Initialize your application singleton
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new HelloAppHost().Init();
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Really enjoying using ServiceStack, It really is a fantastic project so thanks.

**Edit**

So for example:

Calling: `http://localhost:60063/hello/Ian?format=json` returns `{"Result":"Hello, Ian"}`.
Whereas Calling: `http://localhost:60063/hello/I?format=json` returns `{}`.

The second call returns `{}` where I was expecting auto generated error messages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer. It was an overlook on my behalf:

This was in the documentation and I overlooked it:

> All Error handling and validation options described below are treated
>   in the same way - serialized into the ResponseStatus property of your
>   Response DTO making it possible for your clients applications to
>   generically treat all Web Service Errors in the same way.

So all that was missing from my code was to add the following line into the `HelloResponse` class.

> public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }

Comment: Also when using [ServiceStack's New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) the `ResponseStatus` property is only required when your Response DTO follows the convention being named `RequestDtoResponse` because that's the DTO ServiceStack will hydrate the errors into. If no response DTO exists ServiceStack will use the generic **ErrorResponse** DTO (i.e. instead of your Response DTO) which already has the `ResponseStatus` property.